# Dots in a list

Tags: html, css

Can you tell me the code for dotted line on a long list for a table/column i.e.

Cell                    Column
Manicure.............$10.00

Where do I put it in the code as well, don't know css, yes html

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the source language and target media/language?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you're looking for.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, I believe the question is:

"Can someone tell me how to fill the remaining width of a column with dots (a dot leader, as in the example)? Preferably using only html."

Comment: Probably best to change the title to a question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is something I just played around with (tested on IE8 and FF3):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .dotted {
                position:relative;
                border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
                background:white;
                height:24px;
                width:300px;
            }

            .item {
                position:absolute;
                height:26px;
                line-height:30px;
                text-align:left;
                background:white;

            }
            .value {
                position:absolute;
                right:0px;
                height:26px;
                line-height:30px;
                background:white;               
                text-align:right;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="dotted">
            <span class="item">Manicure</span>
            <span class="value">$10.00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="dotted">
            <span class="item">Tanning</span>
            <span class="value">$100.00</span>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: flaw is that if you have a transparent background it sort of not work, but for solid color background you should be fine :)

Comment: similarly, a different approach might be using a transparent .gif / .png containing dotted graphic as the background image for the containing div instead of the border-bottom attribute above.  In that case the actual page background won't matter (will work).

Comment: Would it not be as easy to use <li></li> (and of course use either <ul> or <ol>) instead of the divs? I only ask because the question relates explicitly to 'lists.'

Comment: @drthomas: It just happened that I tried the code with DIV and SPAN.  I don't see why it won't work w/ UL/OL/LI combo.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a dot leader (which is what the dots you're looking for are called) is possible in pure html. You're going to have to use some css.

Here's a nice article that should get you started:

http://web-graphics.com/mtarchive/001622.php

Now that you know the name of what you're looking for, you can also google a bit and look around, but as I said, I think you're probably going to have to use css.